# Can I apply the same extension to many classes without copy paste?

Tags: swift, double, cgfloat

Let's say I have this extension for CGFloat

```
extension CGFloat {
    // common 
    public var thrice: CGFloat { return self * 3.0 }
    public var twice: CGFloat { return self * 2.0 }
    public var half: CGFloat { return self * 0.5 }
    public var third: CGFloat { return self / 3.0 }
    public var fourth: CGFloat { return self * 0.25 }
    public var sixth: CGFloat { return self / 6.0 }
    public var eighth: CGFloat { return self * 0.125 }
    public var twelfth: CGFloat { return self / 12.0 }
    public var sixteenth: CGFloat { return self * 0.0625 }

    //
    public var inverse: CGFloat { return 1.0 / self }
}
```

What I want to do is have these apply to CGFloat, Double and Float without having to copy/paste the code.  Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You cannot do it by extending the types (all at once), but you could do it using templated functions:

```
protocol FloatLiteralMultipliable: FloatLiteralConvertible {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Float: FloatLiteralMultipliable {}
extension CGFloat: FloatLiteralMultipliable {}
extension Double: FloatLiteralMultipliable {}

func thrice<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value * 3.0 }
func twice<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value * 2.0 }
func half<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 2.0 }
func third<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 3.0 }
func fourth<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 4.0 }
func sixth<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 6.0 }
func eighth<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value * 0.125 }
func twelfth<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 12.0 }
func sixteenth<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return value / 0.0625 }

func inverse<T: FloatLiteralMultipliable>(value: T) -> T { return 1.0 / value }

thrice(Float(10.0)) // 30.0
half(CGFloat(2)) // 1.0
inverse(Double(1.0/10.0)) // 10.0
```

**Note:** I am only explicitly constructing the types in my example calls to prove that it the functions can be used with each of the types

Comment: Isn't it better to just extend `integertype`? Also how can they relate to the extenstion when they are after the `{}`

Comment: playgrounds is not letting this compile ... any suggestions or update .. gives warning warning: 'FloatLiteralConvertible' is deprecated: renamed to 'ExpressibleByFloatLiteral' but if i change type to new name still doesn't compile